# Error in Eclipse-Tomcat Setup - ClassNotFoundException "1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging, classnotfoundexception

**Setup:** Eclipse Juno R, Tomcat 7.0.8, tomcat run through eclipse plug in.
Tomcat launch configuration from eclipse has VM argument 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\WS\Serverlogs\tomcat7\conf\logging.properties"
 (Ref: [Where can I view Tomcat log files in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233053/where-can-i-view-tomcat-log-files-in-eclipse))
Getting following error.

```
Can't load log handler "1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:57)
Can't load log handler "1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler"
```

There are similar errors for "1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler","2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler" and others.
I understand that these classes come from tomcat-juli.jar at /bin.
I added this jar into server classpath (Eclipse -> Servers -> Open -> Open Lauch configuration -> Classpath -> User Entries), but got the same error.
Contents of logging.properties are:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = C:\WS\Serverlogs\tomcat7/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = C:\WS\Serverlogs\tomcat7/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = C:\WS\Serverlogs\tomcat7/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = C:\WS\Serverlogs\tomcat7/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Any input / guidance is most appreciated.
Found these 
[How to configure Tomcat JULI logging to roll log files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136300/how-to-configure-tomcat-juli-logging-to-roll-log-files)
[Local Tomcat Environment Not Starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166414/local-tomcat-environment-not-starting)
, but my issue seems to be different.

**Edit1**
Adding "-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager" to server's VM Argument and changing "\" to "/" in the logging.properties did the trick.
Thanks to Robin for the pointer to Tomcat Logging FAQ

Thank you,
VJ

Comment: On windows with tomcat installed as a service and using the tomcat7w.exe to modify the settings on the Java tab > Java Options section; a single space after `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager` before the new line gave me the same issue.

Answer (score 21):

Ensure the following system property is set,

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

As seen [here](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/logging-failure-with-tomcat-6-0-29-jvm-1-6-0-30-b12-ubuntu-10-04-3-LTS-td4531175.html#a4531359) on the tomcat users mailing list.

I had the same problem launching tomcat with [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) instead of using the tomcat startup scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the FAQ for a question about logging not working:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Logging

Or you can use another `logging.properties`, for example this one:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
    
# Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```

Comment: Using ConsoleAppender is not an option for me. I want the logs to be written into a file that I can refer to at later time. Looking at the logging FAQ' for tomcat

Comment: You don't have to use the ConsoleAppender for sure. This is only a sample. Here is the manual of the Apache log4j http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html. You will find there is a FileAppender for Example. This will add you Log to a .log File. Check this link: http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/log4j-tutorial-how-to-send-the-log-messages-to-a-file/